# Как получить ID больше, чем у 50 видео?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, youtube, youtube-api

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь получить идентификаторы более, чем у 50 роликов, используя `nextPageToken`.  Но проблема в том, что каждый раз в переменную `ids` добавляются и идентификаторы с предыдущей итерации - их становится больше 50 - и выполнение запроса крашится. Есть разумные способы как это предотвратить? По итогу необходимо получить все видео по ключевому слову.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Parse(string keyword)
    {
        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "myapikey"
        });

        var nextPageToken = "";
        string part = "snippet, statistics";
        string ids = string.Empty;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var videos = new List<Video>();


        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
            var videosListMultipleIdsRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List(part);
            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");

            searchListRequest.Q = keyword; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            searchListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

            var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                if (searchResult.Id.Kind.Equals("youtube#video"))
                {
                    ids = sb.Append($"{searchResult.Id.VideoId},").ToString();
                }
            }

            ids = ids.Remove(ids.Length - 1);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
            {
                videosListMultipleIdsRequest.Id = ids;
            }

            var response = await videosListMultipleIdsRequest.ExecuteAsync();

            foreach (var item in response.Items)
            {
                videos.Add(item);
            }

            ids = string.Empty;

            nextPageToken = searchListResponse.NextPageToken;
        }

        ViewBag.Videos = videos;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Ну начните с `searchListRequest.MaxResults = 100500;`

Comment: А какой смысл, если максимальное количество результатов с одной страницы - 50 ? При увеличении - http://bit.ly/2oLrJaW

Comment: Не понятно, что значит: "Но проблема в том, что каждый раз в переменную ids добавляются и идентификаторы с предыдущей итерации - их становится больше 50 - и выполнение запроса крашится." Поясните на примере.

Comment: Первое, что пришло на ум. Раз MaxResults = 50, значит надо увеличить и посмотреть, что будет. Если дело не в этом, то рассказывайте в каком именно месте и как именно крашится. Сообщение об ошибке и т.д.

Comment: @Bulson Первый проход по циклу - `nexPageToken = ""`, спарсил ~47 идентификаторов видео, `nextPageToken = searchListResponse.NextPageToken` (изменили токен), второй проход по циклу вернёт идентификаторы с первого прохода и добавит новых (~50), итого получится 97 идентификаторов, соответственно выполнить запрос не удастся (кол-во больше 50)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads тут пример, только выводит список загруженных видео на канале. Использовал эту схему для получения всех видео по ключевому слову.